# About the bounds of accuracy for $\sum_{r=0}^a\binom{a}{r}\sum_{m=0}^r\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}\binom{r}{m}(-1)^{m-k}2^{m-k}\sin(k)=\sin(a)$

Tags: trigonometry

I noticed that the following sine formula:

$$\sum_{r=0}^{a} \binom{a}{r} \sum_{m=0}^{r} \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m}{k} \binom{r}{m} (-1)^{m-k} 2^{m-k} \sin(k) = \sin(a)$$

seem to hold for integer values of 'a' but only numerically up to 7.

8 and above, the formula only approximates to sin(a) and the accuracy becomes worse for larger values of 'a'

May there be a proper reason why? or might it just be a program error?

Comment: This is true for any function, not just sine. See my answer.
The accuracy becoming worse is due to rounding error.

Answer (score 1):

It is true,
and is true for any function,
not just $\sin$.

Here is my
very messy derivation.

There is undoubtedly
a simpler one,
but this is mine.

[A question about the bounds of accuracy for a sine addition formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4718399/a-question-about-the-bounds-of-accuracy-for-a-sine-addition-formula)

$\sum_{r=0}^{a} \binom{a}{r} \sum_{m=0}^{r} \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m}{k} \binom{r}{m} (-1)^{m-k} 2^{m-k} \sin(k) = \sin(a)
$

$\begin{array}\\
s_f(a)
&=\sum_{r=0}^{a} \binom{a}{r} \sum_{m=0}^{r} \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m}{k} \binom{r}{m} (-1)^{m-k} 2^{m-k} f(k)\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{a} \binom{a}{r} \sum_{k=0}^{r}\sum_{m=k}^{r}  \binom{m}{k} \binom{r}{m} (-1)^{m-k} 2^{m-k} f(k)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{a}\sum_{r=k}^{a} \binom{a}{r} \sum_{m=k}^{r}  \binom{m}{k} \binom{r}{m} (-1)^{m-k} 2^{m-k} f(k)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{a}f(k)(-1)^{-k}2^{-k}\sum_{r=k}^{a} \binom{a}{r} \sum_{m=k}^{r}  \binom{m}{k} \binom{r}{m} (-1)^{m} 2^{m} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{a}f(k)(-1)^{-k}2^{-k}\sum_{r=k}^{a} \binom{a}{r} \sum_{m=k}^{r}  \dfrac{m!r!}{k!(m-k)!m!(r-m)!}(-1)^{m} 2^{m} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{a}f(k)(-1)^{-k}2^{-k}\sum_{r=k}^{a} \binom{a}{r} \sum_{m=k}^{r}  \dfrac{r!}{k!(m-k)!(r-m)!}(-1)^{m} 2^{m} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{a}\dfrac{f(k)(-1)^{-k}2^{-k}}{k!}\sum_{r=k}^{a} \dfrac{a!}{r!(a-r)!}r! \sum_{m=k}^{r}  \dfrac{1}{(m-k)!(r-m)!}(-1)^{m} 2^{m} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{a}\dfrac{f(k)(-1)^{-k}2^{-k}}{k!}\sum_{r=k}^{a} \dfrac{a!}{(a-r)!} \sum_{m=k}^{r}  \dfrac{1}{(m-k)!(r-m)!}(-1)^{m} 2^{m} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{a}\dfrac{f(k)(-1)^{-k}2^{-k}}{k!}\sum_{r=k}^{a} \dfrac{a!}{(a-r)!(r-k)!} \sum_{m=k}^{r}  \dfrac{(r-k)!}{(m-k)!(r-m)!}(-1)^{m} 2^{m} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{a}\dfrac{f(k)(-1)^{-k}2^{-k}a!}{k!(a-k)!}\sum_{r=k}^{a} \dfrac{(a-k)!}{(a-r)!(r-k)!} \sum_{m=k}^{r}  \dfrac{(r-k)!}{(m-k)!(r-m)!}(-1)^{m} 2^{m} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{a}f(k)(-1)^{-k}2^{-k}\binom{a}{k}\sum_{r=k}^{a} \binom{a-k}{r-k}\sum_{m=k}^{r}  \binom{r-k}{r-m}(-1)^{m} 2^{m} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{a}f(k)(-1)^{-k}2^{-k}\binom{a}{k}\sum_{r=k}^{a} \binom{a-k}{r-k}\sum_{m=0}^{r-k}  \binom{r-k}{r-(m+k)}(-1)^{m+k} 2^{m+k} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{a}f(k)\binom{a}{k}\sum_{r=k}^{a} \binom{a-k}{r-k}\sum_{m=0}^{r-k}  \binom{r-k}{r-k-m}(-2)^{m}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{a}f(k)\binom{a}{k}\sum_{r=k}^{a} \binom{a-k}{r-k}(1-2)^{r-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{a}f(k)\binom{a}{k}\sum_{r=k}^{a} \binom{a-k}{r-k}(-1)^{r-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{a}f(k)\binom{a}{k}\sum_{r=0}^{a-k} \binom{a-k}{r}(-1)^{r}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{a}f(k)\binom{a}{k}(1-1)^{a-k}\\
&=f(a)\\
\end{array}
$

since
$(1-1)^{a-k}=0
$
if $a-k>0$
and $1$
if $a=k$.